# Using MaxStepFraction as ticks on plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Is there any way I could use the `MaxStepFraction` (or grid size) as used in `NDSolve` in the example below as ticks on the 3d Plot?

That was I would be able to plot the grid points on the X and Y axis.

I tried creating a table and using that as the argument in `Ticks` but that didn't work.

Minimum working example:

```
Clear[u, L, t, x, y, sol, Eq]
L = 4;
Eq = -D[u[t, x, y], t, t] + D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + 
   D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + Sin[u[t, x, y]];
uSol = u /. NDSolve[{
     Eq == 0, u[t, -L, y] == u[t, L, y], 
     u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L], 
     u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], 
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0
     }, 
    u,
     {t, 0, L/2}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L},
    MaxStepFraction -> 1/11
    ][[1]]




tt = 1.2;
Plot3D[ uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, 2/5, 4/5, 6/5, 8/5, 2, 12/5, 14/5, 16/5, 18/5, 4}, {0, 
    2/5, 4/5, 6/5, 8/5, 2, 12/5, 14/5, 16/5, 18/5, 4}}]
```

[image]

The ticks in the above figure were created using, `Table[i 4/10, {i, 10}]` and then manually pasted into the curly brackets. Obviously, that isn't the most efficient way.

I tried pasting the `Table` command inside `Plot3D` but that didn't work.

Comment: Try `Ticks -> Evaluate[{Table[(* stuff *)], (* other ticks *)}]`; `Plot3D[]` is `HoldAll`, see...

Comment: @J.M. `Evaluate`.... hmm... I never thought of that. This isn't the first time I've come across this `Evaluate`...

Comment: @J.M. Are my questions really poor? I thought I'd ask.

Comment: Well, they aren't poor *per se*... I suppose the `HoldAll` attribute of plotting functions isn't really obvious at first glance.

Comment: @drN No, your question style improves! Compared to your last one this example is really small, self-contained and illustrative. Therefore a +1 for the question.

Comment: @drN Can you point out, why `Table` didn't work? For me something like `Plot3D[uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y,0, L}, Ticks -> Table[x, {3}, {x, 0, 4, 1/3}]]` does work, even with the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot3D`.

Comment: @halirutan I am away from mathematica right now. I'll try to post my error message soon.

Comment: @halirutan strangely, like you mention, even with the `HoldAll` attribute, it works. I wonder if it was previously a stray key stroke? I don't believe that to be the case. I had also restarted the kernel...

Comment: @drN If you have a function with `HoldAll` it doesn't mean you have to evaluate everything (like the options) to make it work. The `HoldAll` is not a problem, but what can be problematic is when the function like `Plot` make a check inside whether e.g. your `Ticks` are really a `List`. Then it sees the `Table`, thinks there is something wrong and returns with an error. Very simple example: `a = {10}; Table[1, a]` compared to `Table[1,Evaluate[a]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tt = 1.2;
Plot3D[uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
      Ticks -> {Table[i 4/10, {i, 10}], Table[i 4/10, {i, 10}]}
]
```

or the slightly more concise version of mr.wizard:

```
Plot3D[uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, 
  Ticks -> ({#, #} & @ Table[i 4/10, {i, 10}])
]
```

yield:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

or, since you wanted to use your setting for `MaxStepFraction` (1/11), you could use `FindDivisions` with that value:

```
tt = 1.2;
Plot3D[uSol[tt, x, y], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
      Ticks -> {FindDivisions[{0, L, 1/11}, 10],FindDivisions[{0, L, 1/11}, 10]}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looks like I lost.  If you add the concise `{#, #}` form I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ;-P Looks like it. Perhaps time to go to bed?

Comment: Why do you need such a big `Function` construct? Was `Table[i 4/10, {2}, {i, 10}]` too simple? ;-)

Comment: This is definitely a good answer like the other one `:P`. However, haliurtan's answer/comment is simplicity itself. I don't quite understand why it didn't work previously.

Comment: @drN No! A single Table doesn't give the ticks as you showed in the figure in your question. Besides, you'd need to place {} around it, otherwise you'd get errors. (that might even have been the error that plagued you)

Comment: Actually, I got an error with `{}` around my `Table`. I used two tables and things worked fine.

Comment: @drN I use two Tables too, so what's the difference?